# ANTLR Grammar not

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I started writing another C-like language a few days ago and I've gotten stuck here.

The "pointers" rule seems to be colliding with the `*` operator in the OP token and making the `*` operator not recognized in the "expr" rule, and same for the `&` operator with the "reference" rule. How can I fix this?

```
grammar C;

program
  : (include | var_decl | boigaCall ';' | func_decl | typedef ';')*;

stmt
  : if_stmt
  | repeat_stmt
  | var_decl
  | var_change
  | function_call ';'
  | return_stmt ';'
  | boigaCall ';'
  | switch_stmt
  | '{' stmt* '}';

if_stmt
  : if_part else_part?;

if_part
  : 'if' paren_expr stmt;

else_part
  : 'else' stmt;

repeat_stmt
  : 'repeat' '(' expr ')' stmt;

var_decl
  : type name=ID ('=' expr)? ';';

var_change
  : pointers? name=ID ('=' | VARIABLE_MODIFIER) expr ';';

func_decl
  : (inline='inline')? type recursion? noturbo? name=ID '(' functionArgs ')' stmt;

functionArgs
  : ((ID name=ID) (',' ID name=ID)*?)?;

recursion
  : '!';

noturbo
  : '?';

paren_expr
  : '(' expr ')';

function_call
  : ID '(' expr? (',' expr)* ')';

return_stmt
  : 'return' expr?;

typedef
  : 'typedef' structdef ID;

structdef
  : 'struct' '{' (structelem ';')+ '}';

switch_stmt
  : 'switch' paren_expr switch_chain;

switch_chain
  : '{' case_block+ default_block? '}';

case_block
  : 'case' expr ':' stmt* 'break' ';';

default_block
  : 'default' ':' stmt*;

structelem
  : typedName;

typedName
  : ID name=ID;

expr
  : pointers expr
  | term
  | expr OP expr
  | cast expr
  | '(' expr ')';

term
  : ID | INT | HEX | BIN | FLOAT | STRING | boigaCall | sizeOf | function_call | reference ID;

sizeOf
  : 'sizeof' '(' ID ')';

boigaCall
  : '__boiga' '(' STRING (',' expr)* ')';

cast
  : '(' type ')';

pointers
: '*'+;

reference
: '&';

type
  : ID pointers?;

include
  : '#include' (LIBRARY | STRING);


fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment LETTER: [a-zA-Z];
fragment HEX_CHAR: [a-fA-F];

STRING        : '"' (~'"'|'\\"')* '"';
LIBRARY       : '<' [a-zA-Z.]* '>';
ID            : (LETTER | '_')+ (LETTER | '_' | DIGIT)*;
INT           : '-'? DIGIT+;
HEX           : '0x' (DIGIT | HEX_CHAR)+;
BIN           : '0b' ('0' | '1')+;
FLOAT         : '-'? DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+;
VARIABLE_MODIFIER : OP '=';
OP            : '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '%' | '==' | '!=' | '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' | '&&' | '||' | '&' | '|' | '^' | '>>' | '<<';

COMMENT       : SINGLE_COMMENT | BLOCK_COMMENT;
SINGLE_COMMENT: '//' .*? '\n';
BLOCK_COMMENT : '/*' .*? '*/';
WS: ([ \t\r\n] | COMMENT)+ -> skip;
```

I tried making `*` and `&` into their own token and using those tokens in the "pointers" and "reference" rule, but that only caused the `&` and `*` tokens to be seen as operators again, but not as pointers/reference anymore. I tested the "program" rule with `var x = a*b;` and `var x = a&b;`, which tests the rule that is not properly working.

Comment: Have you tried reading ANTLR4 example grammars of similar languages to see how they solved the issue? For exampe the [Tiny C grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/tinyc/tinyc.g4).

Comment: `*` and `&` *are* operators.  Each is two different operators, in fact -- a binary one and a unary one.  The same is true of `-` and `+`, too, as far as C itself is concerned.  The C language spec (see [this draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3047.pdf), for example) devotes considerably more grammar productions to expressions than you're trying to get away with.  That serves several purposes, but one is certainly to show how to distinguish uses of `+`, `-`, `&`, `*` as unary operators from uses of the same as binary operators.  You should study that.

Comment: Never make a lexer rule that collapses all operators into one token type. `OP            : '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '%' | '==' | '!=' | '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' | '&&' | '||' | '&' | '|' | '^' | '>>' | '<<';`. Just rename it to a parser rule, similar for VARIABLE_MODIFIER.  It interferes with working out the rules for the precedence and associativity of operators in the grammar. Best if you read the [C grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/7ec03688034bfe4d98f81accaa2ee421496f3c47/c/C.g4) and see how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just move `'*'` out of `OP`, everything works just fine. Your grammar created an implicit token when you used `'*'` inside of the `pointers` rule, so these `*`'s are always that token and never `OP`.

When you create a token rule for this specific literal, Antlr tracks it down, and doesn't create its double. Therefore it allows the user to type either `'*'` or `POW`.

```
expr
  : term
  | pointers expr
  | expr (OP | POW) expr
  | cast expr
  | '(' expr ')';

POW: '*';
OP: '+' | '-' | '/' | '%' | '==' | '!=' | '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' | '&&' | '||' | '&' | '|' | '^' | '>>' | '<<';
```

Input: `a*b*c`

[image: Parse tree 1]

Input: `a***b`

[image: Parse tree 2]

Comment: The image is hardly readable. I suggest [cropping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image)) it, etc. Also, the input text ought to [be provided as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) as well (it covers answers as well).